# Assign values to numerically-named variable from an arraylist

Tags: java

The legacy code i'm working on uses 21 numerically-named attributes for a class, for 3 differents things (lets call them "firstThing", "secondThing", and "thirdThing").
So I have the firstThing1, firstThing2, ... firstThing7 attributes in my class, and the same for secondThing and thirdThing.

Everywhere in the code where objects of that class are used, it's just pieces of code copied 7 times that *all do the same thing*, beside of using the correct numerically-named attribute. Not so great.

Instead of changing the whole picture and redesigning the class, i wanted to at least change the functions i'm working on : doing a loop with the redundant code, add the values to a specific ArrayList where they were previously assigned. Now I would know if there is a way to take all those values from my ArrayList, and assign them to the specific numerically-named attribute ? Or a way to test the length of the differents ArrayList and assign values to that many number of attributes ? Or should I just copy

```
if(listOfFirstThings.size() >= 1)
  myObject.setFirstThing1(listOfFirstThings.get(0));

if(listOfFirstThings.size() >= 2)
  myObject.setFirstThing2(listOfFirstThings.get(1));

...
```

21 times to assign everything I need ?

Comment: You have sent the code in to the [Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redesigning the class *is* the way to go. You've effectively got three collections - which should quite possibly be *one* collection, with each element having three properties.

Java just isn't designed to use execution-time-generated variable names. You *can* do it with reflection, but I would strongly encourage you to fix it properly right now. (I'd actually do this as a refactoring step before trying to add whatever new feature you're working on.)

Comment: Well, what i'm doing right now is already more of a refactoring than adding a new feature, so i guess i'll just go that way and change this crap to something maintainable :p
Thanks